# Sqlite Library for Python

Tags: sqlite, python-2.7

Is there any link to download SQLite Library for Python 2.7?

I'm particularly interested in working with a SQLite Library for Python.i tried googling it , but the links provided are not actually links to SQLite Library ,most of them is to download the SQLite. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's built-in.  I don't think you actually need to download anything except maybe the command line SQLite client so you can run queries without python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/stdlib.html#batteries-included) says:

> Python has a “batteries included” philosophy.

The [sqlite3 module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) is built in:

```
$ python
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect('/tmp/test.db')
>>> c = conn.cursor()
>>> c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t(x)") 
>>> c.execute("INSERT INTO t VALUES(42)")
>>> c.execute("SELECT * FROM t")
>>> c.fetchall()
[(42,)]
```